# derivative multiplied by value

Tags: integration

I have a simple question which I am a little puzzled by. Why
derivative multiplied by value can look like this

$$\frac{dv}{dt}\,v\,=\,\frac12 \frac{dv^2}{dt}\;\;?$$

I understand the change part $dv/dt$, however what I don't understand is how you can take integral of $v$ and merge it with derivative.

Comment: Hello Sil. Your question is not clear. Are you looking for to find out the derivative of a vector or just random variable please? Taking derivative simply means finding rate of change for how variable $v$ changes with respect to $t$. If $v$ is a variable, then it would be $\frac{dv}{dt} = 1$. You can apply the concept of limit to find the derivative as it will make much more sense to you. Ask me if you have more questions please.

Comment: it's because of the "chain rule". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{dv^{2}}{dt} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{dv^{2}}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\,2v\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dt}\, v$

Answer (score 0):

This is just the chain rule. Since $(v^2)’ = 2 v v’$: $$ v v’ = \frac{1}{2} (v^2)’$$
Here $v’$ stands for $\frac{dv}{dt}$